# Adding an array of same variable names in yaml file

Tags: yaml

for this website, it takes information from a authors.Yaml file.

this file holds the detail for the demo author.

```
authors:
  - slug: wutali
    name: Takahiro Fujiwara
    introduction:
      Co-founder and CTO at Fuller, Inc. / Software & Data Engineer /
      Python / Golang / React
```

however, I wish to put in my information.

```
  - slug: Hemming
    name: Alexander Hemming
    introduction:
      Developer, React, Node, Sveltekit, Goland.
    - slug: Owner
    name: John Doe
    introduction:
    Founder and CEO at a company.
```

adding this to the end doesn't seem to work. How would I make it some that this information is accessible for additional potential authors?

Comment: Make sure you `yml` is correctly formatted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two indentation errors:

```yaml
  - slug: Hemming
    name: Alexander Hemming
    introduction:
      Developer, React, Node, Sveltekit, Goland.
  - slug: Owner   # fixed indentation to be on par with previous item
    name: John Doe
    introduction: # next line must be more indented to be the value
                  # of this key.
      Founder and CEO at a company.
```